# ASP.NET/C# - Entity Framework - Classes - Skeleton Method

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, entity-framework

I currently have a Class which uses the function as such:

```
var txbl = test.search_bustype("SUP", "Name");
```

or

```
foreach(string toWorkWith in test.search_bustype("SUP", "Name")){ // each one }
```

However, for every Column I want to search using a function, I have to create a separate function.

ie: Columns - bustype, companyID - Would have to have separate functions to search.

My current code is:

```
public Array search_bustype(string match, string forthat)
    {
        db = new rkdb_07022016Entities2();
        var tbl = (from c in db.tblbus_business select c).ToArray();
        List<string> List = new List<string>();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var toCheck in tbl)
        {
            if (toCheck.BusType.ToString() == match)
            {
                if (forthat == "Name")
                {
                    List.Add(toCheck.Name);
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
        return List.ToArray();
    }
```

Is there anyway to possibly, like `php` actually send the `query` to the function and then run it there? I haven't been able to find many sources about how to build a secure infrastructure with Entity so I am wondering if anyone knows any way of maybe creating a `skeleton` method with this framework.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: dispose the context, avoid Array, use generics. If you want to return two different things (full object or a string) then create two separate methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I stumbled on the Frameworks sources and actually now understand that the Framework itself implements the `Skeleton` method.

You simply only refer to each query inside the `(from c in......`

I'll have to look further into how this infrastructure works before I can understand how to further implement functions.

Thank-you for your time however! I will close this.